How do I run my java code on my JFrame in eclipse?
I'm currently trying to create what I thought was going to be an easy Java program. I want to create a GUI that prompts the user to enter the day of the week and will spit out the chores they have to do that day. I also wanted check boxes next to the chores to be able to mark off what is completed. I can get the code to run fine in the console window (minus the check boxes obviously) but I don't know  how to make my code run on the JFrame I created. I know there is also a way to add labels, buttons, textboxes, etc. without actually writing the code and just plotting them on the JFrame, but I can't get my frame to appear without running the code, so it's not editable.
This is where my code sits so far:
/**
 * @author AMoore
 * @date 4/4/24
 * The purpose of this program  is to prompt a user to enter a day of the week, give them  the daily chores, and allow them to check them off. 
 * 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ChoreChartBuilder {
    
    JFrame frame;
    
    public ChoreChartBuilder() {
        initComponenent();
    }
    
    public void initComponenent() {
        frame = new JFrame("Daily Chore Chart");
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChoreChartBuilder();
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String mon = "Monday";
        String tue = "Tuesday";
        String wed = "Wednesday";
        String thu = "Thursday";
        String fri = "Friday";
        String sat = "Saturday";
        String sun = "Sunday";
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the day of the week: ");
        
        String day = input.nextLine();
        
        input.close();
        
        if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(mon)) {
            System.out.println("Monday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(tue)) {
            System.out.println("Tuesday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(wed)) {
            System.out.println("Wednesday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(thu)) {
            System.out.println("Thursday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(fri)) {
            System.out.println("Friday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(sat)) {
            System.out.println("Saturday Chores: ");
        }
        else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(sun)) {
            System.out.println("Sunday Chores: ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("A day of the week was not entered. Goodbye.");
        }
    
    
    }
}


This isn't a good SO question because it is too vague. You should probably stick to a particular task. What do you want to do first? Eg. I want a window to appear with a button. When the user clicks the button it opens a dialog to choose the data.

i don't understand the "but I can't get my frame to appear without running the code, so it's not editable." part. If you want your output to appear in the GUI, you need to add a JLabel/JTextArea/... to the JFrame and add your output to that JLabels instead of calling System.out.println.

As f1sh said above you need to add components to your JFrame like so frame.add(component); or frame.add(new JLabel("Label text"));. A great place to learn how this works is the official Java tutorial on creating a GUI here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html You will quickly see how it works and be able to add your own components with ease.

It's been some time since I last used Eclipse and I don't know the current pre-installed plug-ins but in the past you needed to install something like this https://eclipse.dev/windowbuilder/ for being able to drag-and-drop swing components. In any case, as stated by the other users, it's not clear what you are asking exactly.

@RubioRic Yes the window builder was getting me stuck! I didn't want to "manually" code every button, feature etc. Thank you!

@sorifiend Thank you! This java tutorial was really helpful!

@f1sh Sorry, it was hard trying to explain what I meant, but Rubioric and Sorifiend were able to figure out what I was trying to say lol thanks!

Here is a complete compilable example using a java GUI.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class DayChooser{

    void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        List<String> days = List.of("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" );
        JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(days.toArray(new String[0]));
        JList<String> chores = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<>());

        box.addActionListener( evt->{
           DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)chores.getModel();
           model.clear();

           model.addElement(box.getSelectedItem() + " chores");
           model.addElement("refactor code");
           model.addElement("write tests");
           model.addElement("Do java swing tutorial");
        });
        //add some junk for layout purposes.
        DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>)chores.getModel();
        model.addElement("chores by day");
        model.addElement("1.");
        model.addElement("2.");
        model.addElement("3.");
        model.addElement("4.");

        frame.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(chores, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

       DayChooser dc = new DayChooser();
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( dc::buildGui );

    }

}

Your program flow should react to gui events. Eg. In this example you select a day and it populates a list. You'll probably want to make a class to represent a chore.

Or maybe JComboBox<DayOfWeek> box = new JComboBox<>(DayOfWeek.values());, which would naturally internationalize
